# Net::Telnet and Chinese characters

Tags: perl, telnet

I'm having difficulty dealing with (Traditional) Chinese characters when outputting text using Perl Net::Telnet. For instance, if I connect to ptt.cc (based in Taiwan), the text output does not have the correct character encoding.

Here's a very simple example:

```
use Net::Telnet (); 
$t = new Net::Telnet; 
$t->open("ptt.cc"); 

$contents = $t->get;

print $contents;

exit;
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is somewhat outside standards land, as Telnet was supposed to be ASCII. Try passing bin_mode => 1 to Net::Telnet->new, and doing the decoding of lines yourself with Encode. See Encode::CN for a simplified charset encodings to try.

Comment: Thanks for that, @FrankRalphBob. I've been trying various tricks with Encode, but with no luck so far. Will post my results here if I find a winner!